# Swift Firebase Like Post in Table View

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am implementing a Question&Answer program in Swift, using Firebase. I want to have a like button in my tableViewCell. However, I am having problem because the post's data is in the tableView class and I can make changes on the like button in tableViewCell class. I need a data transfer between these two. Can anyone help me with this?

If it is going to help you to understand my problem, code in my table view:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let answerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AnswerCell") as! AnswerCell

        let answer = answers[indexPath.row]

        answerCell.answerText.text = answer.answerText
        answerCell.username.text = "~ \(answer.username)"
        answerCell.numberOfLikes.text = "\(answer.numberOflikes) liked this answer."

        answerCell.answerText.numberOfLines = 0

        return answerCell
    }
```

I want to have a code like this in my table view cell. However, I cannot access the answer object's data.

```
 @IBAction func likeButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("answerLikes").child((answer.id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
        (snapshot) in
        if let _ = snapshot.value as? NSNull {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "filledHeart.png"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            answerLikes = [Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid : true]
            ref.child("answerLikes").child(answer.id).updateChildValues(answerLikes)
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "emptyHeart.png"), for: .normal)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Where method `likeButtonClicked` are placed?

Comment: It is in the AnswerCell. Should it be in the table view controller? Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

This is solution where you asked "I cannot access the answer object's data"

You can create a method in answerCell which receive an answer object.

```
func recieveAnswerObject(answer : Answer){
  // here you will get answer object
   // here i am assuming Answer is your model class
 }
```

// now time to call it from  your main UIViewController class to send answer object

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let answerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AnswerCell") as! AnswerCell

    let answer = answers[indexPath.row]
    // from here we send answer object
    answerCell.recieveAnswerObject(answer)
    answerCell.answerText.text = answer.answerText
    answerCell.username.text = "~ \(answer.username)"
    answerCell.numberOfLikes.text = "\(answer.numberOflikes) liked this answer."

    answerCell.answerText.numberOfLines = 0

    return answerCell
}
```

Now for the part where you asked how to data transfer between these two class

First way to achieve this

1.Make a delegate in AnswerCell class and confirm it to your Controller where you have written your tableView code.

2.When button is clicked fire a delegate and you will get callback in your mainViewController.

Second way to achieve this

1.Make an IBOulet for likeButtonClicked in AnswerCell class.

2.Dont't make IBAction.

3.Your code will look something like this

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let answerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AnswerCell") as! AnswerCell
   // action added to button
    answerCell.likeButtonClicked.addTarget(self, action: #selector(likeButtonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    // updated set tag to button
    answerCell.likeButtonClicked.tag = indexPath.row
    let answer = answers[indexPath.row]
    answerCell.answerText.text = answer.answerText
    answerCell.username.text = "~ \(answer.username)"
    answerCell.numberOfLikes.text = "\(answer.numberOflikes) liked this answer."

    answerCell.answerText.numberOfLines = 0

    return answerCell
}
```

and write your below code in your tableview class

```
 @IBAction func likeButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
 //updated now tag is row position of button in cell and is equal to       (indexPath.row) of that particular button.tag is equal to 
let tag = sender.tag
 // here indexPath.row can be replace by tag so
  //let answer = answers[indexPath.row] == let answer = answers[tag]
  // updated till here
ref = Database.database().reference()

ref.child("answerLikes").child((answer.id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
    (snapshot) in
    if let _ = snapshot.value as? NSNull {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "filledHeart.png"), for: .normal)
    } else {
        answerLikes = [Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid : true]
        ref.child("answerLikes").child(answer.id).updateChildValues(answerLikes)
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "emptyHeart.png"), for: .normal)
    }
})
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but in likeButtonClicked action to be created in the table view, I cannot write "child(answer.id)" since I don't have answer. I keep answers list and access a single answer as answers[indexPath.row] in table view function. Any help about this please?

Comment: You can check my updated answer.I have marked as updated where i have made changes.Hope you will get your answer.Let me know if face any issue regarding above solution

Comment: I got my answer, this is the exact solution that I need. Thank you so much for your response!